# How to submit all R scripts in a directory using with a single .sh file with qsub?

Tags: r, batch-processing, bioinformatics, rscript, qsub

I have a directory `diffexp` with 50 `R` scripts, which are called `diffexpRcommands_neurons_nn.R` (where `nn` is a number from `00` TO `50`.

I would like to run as many of them as possible in parallel on a cluster.

Is there a way in which I can submit all the scripts using `qsub`, but without having to create an individuaal `.sh` script for each `.R` script?

Essentially, I am running differential expression tests between pairs of cell clusters (using the Seurat function `FindMarkers()`.

Since there are 52 cell clusters, there are 1,326 comparisons to make. 
I've generated a command for each of the combinations, and then split those commands into 50 different files, with ~25 comparisons in each one. 
The idea is to try to run every set of 25 commands at once, or at least as many as possible.

Each `diffexpRcommands_neurons_nn.R`script contains the same header:

```
source("/path/to/code/setupCSE.R")
library(gmodels)
library(Matrix)
library(RANN)
library(igraph)

load(file="/path/to/seuratobjects/alltogether_neurons.RData")
```

Followed by 26 comparisons between pairs of cell clusters:

```
# 1 vs 2
cluster1vs2.markers <- FindMarkers(alltogether_neurons, "1", "2")
write.table (cluster1vs2.markers,
 "/path/to/alltogether_neurons_1vs2_markers.txt",
  sep="\t", quote=F, col.names=NA)

# 1 vs 3
    cluster1vs3.markers <- FindMarkers(alltogether_neurons, "1", "3")
write.table (cluster1vs3.markers,
 "/path/to/alltogether_neurons_1vs3_markers.txt",
  sep="\t", quote=F, col.names=NA)

.
.
.
```

and so on, until the end of the last file `diffexpRcommands_neurons_50.R`:

```
# 51 vs 53
    cluster51vs52.markers <- FindMarkers(alltogether_neurons, "51", "52")
    write.table (cluster1vs3.markers,
      "/path/to/alltogether_neurons_51vs52_markers.txt",
      sep="\t", quote=F, col.names=NA)
```

I started this thinking I could somehow run a job array, but I don't know if this is possible since each job is a different set of commands (different set of combinations).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster() # adjust depending on needs.

files <- list.files('/diffexp', pattern = '.R*')
parLapply(cl, files, source)
```

Comment: Thank you @Axeman. I hadn't thought of combining `source` with `parLapply` at all! Is there any disadvantage to doing it this way over `qsub`? Or is my `qsub` idea plainly impossible?

Comment: Another thing I wonder is - with qsub I could request more than 1 node, whereas I believe `makeCluster()` will only let me work on 1 node, albeit several cores. But I'm not sure that's the case.